# No Java Classes in my WAR folder

Tags: java, class, http-status-code-404, war

I was wondering if anyone can help me?

I have a maven project in eclipse which when deployed in my development environment everything works fine. The moment I put it into the live environment things go wrong. I kept getting 404 errors whenever I clicked on a link. While investigation the issue, I found that all my java classes were missing from within my WAR. When I looked inside the 'classes' folder in the unzipped war directory (`projectName/WEB-INF/classes`) it was empty.

Any ideas?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: did you try to do `mvn package` in console?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. 'mvn package' worked however I would have thought 'mvn clean install' would have done the job too? It seems like when I do a 'mvn clean install' the war in packaged without my java classes however when I do a 'mvn package' the java classes are packaged into my war. Any ideas?

Comment: There is evidently something odd going on. Do you have non-standard project layout? Could you post some of your POM?

Comment: <build>
   <finalName>primesc</finalName>
 <plugins>
  <plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.2</version>
   <configuration>
    <source>1.6</source>
    <target>1.6</target>
   </configuration>
  </plugin>
  
  <plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
   <executions>
    <execution>
     <id>install</id>
     <phase>install</phase>
     <goals><goal>sources</goal></goals>
    </execution>
   </executions>
  </plugin>
 </plugins>
</build>

Answer (score 3):

`mvn package` resolved the problem to me

Comment: my problem was with java version. I had 1.8.101 and had to update to 1.8.144, then maven could recognize sources files at src/main/java